# Probability truncation method $P(|S_n| \ge \epsilon) \le P(|S_{n,\le N}| \ge \epsilon/2) + P(|S_{n,>N}| \ge \epsilon/2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $X_i$ are iid random variables and let split it as 
$$X_i = X_{i,\le N} + X_{i,>N}$$ 
where $X_{i,\le N} = X_i\textbf{I}(|X_i|\le N)$ and $X_{i,> N} = X_i\textbf{I}(|X_i|> N)$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and similarly split $S_n$ as
$$S_n = S_{n,\le N} + S_{n,>N}$$ 
where $S_{n,\le N} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,\le N}$ and $S_{n,>N} =\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,> N}$.

I am not sure how to show 
$$ P(|S_n| \ge \epsilon) \le P(|S_{n,\le N}| \ge \epsilon/2) + P(|S_{n,>N}| \ge \epsilon/2) $$
for some $\epsilon > 0$.

In the book I read ([Tao's random matrix theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf), especially, pdf page p86, book page p78, in the proof of Thm 2.1.7.), I think this argument is used. 
As there is no explanation on this, I am assuming it is somewhat trivial. But I am not sure how this can be done.

Here is my trial.
Certainly, $|S_n| \ge \epsilon$ implies $|S_{n,\le N}| + |S_{n,> N}| \ge \epsilon$, from the triangular inequality.
Thus 
$$ P(|S_n| \ge \epsilon) \le P(|S_{n,\le N}| + |S_{n,> N}| \ge \epsilon)$$
However I am not sure how the probability in the right handside could be smaller than $P(|S_{n,\le N}| \ge \epsilon/2) + P(|S_{n,>N}| \ge \epsilon/2)$.

Any comments or answers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\{ |S_n| \ge \epsilon \} \subseteq  \{  |S_{n, \le N}| \ge \epsilon/2 \}  \cup \{ |S_{n, > N} | \ge \epsilon/2 \}$ . . . now 
use the following two facts

- if $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \le P(B)$
- $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) \le P(A) + P(B)$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I was being stupid.